# Any good resource for MOSFET op-amp design?

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet

I've been trying to design a two-stage op-amp for a week, but I haven't been progressing much. Does anyone know good resources that teach you how to design an op-amp (transistor level), preferably with examples?

Answer (score 2):

Analog Integrated Circuit Design
David A. Johns, Ken Martin
Copyright 1997
Chapter 5

To really understand op-amps though, you'll want to understand current-mirrors and single stage amplifiers. The book is fantastic in this regard as it takes you through the basics all the way up.

This separate link has lots of examples of topologies of op-amps:
http://courses.ece.ubc.ca/488/notes/eece488_set7_2up.pdf
Without the background I spoke to before, I doubt you'll understand the reason's behind the topologies shown there tho.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. I understand the basics, but there are gaps in understanding which I can't adequately explain. So for simple circuits everything simulates correctly but not for slightly more complicated topologies like folded cascode or two-stage. It's hard to see why when there is no example to refer to.